# eval throwing error with try/catch

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, actionscript, air, eval

I have an air application, in which the user types javascript in a textarea, and it is eval'd in an mx:HTML component, but even with try/catch around the eval, and around the code in the eval, and an HTMLUncaughtScriptExceptionEvent handler, it still throws an error. **htmlWindow is html.htmlLoader.window**.

```
try { htmlWindow.eval("try {" + script.text + "} catch (error:Error) { trace(error) }); } catch (error:Error) { trace(error) }
```

The application errors on that line as soon as I enter text in `script`, with

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: d
    at Main/reloadHTML()[C:\Users\Christian\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\JavaScript plus Scratch\src\Main.mxml:264]
    at Main/__script_change()[C:\Users\Christian\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\JavaScript plus Scratch\src\Main.mxml:324]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:13128]
    at spark.components.supportClasses::SkinnableTextBase/textDisplay_changeHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\supportClasses\SkinnableTextBase.as:2265]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:13128]
    at spark.components::RichEditableText/textContainerManager_flowOperationCompleteHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\RichEditableText.as:4808]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flashx.textLayout.container::TextContainerManager/dispatchEvent()[C:\Vellum\branches\v2\2.0\dev\output\openSource\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\container\TextContainerManager.as:1553]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flashx.textLayout.elements::TextFlow/dispatchEvent()[C:\Vellum\branches\v2\2.0\dev\output\openSource\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\elements\TextFlow.as:859]
    at flashx.textLayout.edit::EditManager/finalizeDo()[C:\Vellum\branches\v2\2.0\dev\output\openSource\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\edit\EditManager.as:669]
    at flashx.textLayout.edit::EditManager/doOperation()[C:\Vellum\branches\v2\2.0\dev\output\openSource\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\edit\EditManager.as:613]
    at flashx.textLayout.edit::EditManager/flushPendingOperations()[C:\Vellum\branches\v2\2.0\dev\output\openSource\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\edit\EditManager.as:873]
    at flashx.textLayout.edit::SelectionManager/enterFrameHandler()[C:\Vellum\branches\v2\2.0\dev\output\openSource\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\edit\SelectionManager.as:1859]`
```

Any way to stop the error? I tried `script.change="html.htmlText = '<script>' + script.text + '</script'>"`, but I have `htmlWindow.log = log; htmlWindow.rotateSprite = rotateSprite;`, and if i copy-paste `log('test')` in before changing it, it works, if I change it before or after, it never works again, so I'm hoping to get this eval working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can get this code to be 100% exception free. A user could write completely invalid code like `zlçrza ;à"çé°$` which would not throw an exception but simply crash the JS compiler. Could you explain why you let users type javascript code directly? Perhaps you need to approach this problem some other way?